# Як краще перекласти "You can configure application ..."?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Чи можна перекласти "You can *configure* application..." як "Ви можете *налагодити*..."?

У мене виникли сумніви чи правильно перекладати *configure* як *налагодити*. Адже налагодити

> Приводити що-небудь до нормального стану; створювати, організовувати,
>   здійснювати що-небудь.

І в контексті програми для мене особисто це звучить неприродньо.

Comment: Див. також: [«Програму налаштовують чи настроюють?»](/q/4132).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Є декілька кандидатів на роль відповідника *to configure* (щодо програми) різного ступеню пригожості:

- [відрегулювати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13564&page=441) (див. також [регулювати](http://sum.in.ua/s/reghuljuvaty));
- [налагодити](http://sum.in.ua/s/nalaghodzhuvaty) (див. також [лагодити](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46551&page=1469));
- [наладити](http://sum.in.ua/s/naladzhuvaty) (див. також [ладити](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46568&page=1469)) — і таке слово є (і це не росіянізм, обидва слова — і *лагодити*, і *ладити* — походять з праслов'янської й раніше широко вживалися в українській), хоч воно зараз рідко вживається;
- [наладнати](http://sum.in.ua/s/naladnaty) (див. також [ладнати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46577&page=1469)) — аналогічно;
- [налаштувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/nalashtovuvaty) (див. також [лаштувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46950&page=1482));
- [настроїти](http://sum.in.ua/s/nastrojuvaty);
- сконфігурувати (див. [конфігурувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=205452&page=1386)).

(Так само, як і англійською можна висловитися декількома способами: [configure](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/configure), [set up](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set_up), [tune up](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tune_up) тощо.)

Може, я упереджений, але мені особисто *налагоджувати* **не подобається**. Спробую пояснити чому. Wiktionary наводить для *configure* таке тлумачення:

> (transitive) To set up or arrange something in such a way that it is ready for operation for a particular purpose, or **to someone's particular liking** [виділення моє]

— тобто є два можливі випадки вживання: «коли щось зовсім не працює (зовсім не здатне виконувати певне призначення), зробити, щоб воно працювало» і «коли щось працює (виконує певне призначення), зробити так, щоб воно працювало (виконувало певне призначення) по-іншому, більш відповідно до чиїхось уподобань» (тобто конфігурувати можна і речі, що зовсім несконфігуровані, і речі, що загалом сконфігуровані, але ми хочемо переконфігурувати їх). Тому (якщо ми не знаємо, в якому саме контексті вжилося оригінальне *configure*) важливо, щоби в українського відповідника були ті сами два можливі значення. В українського *налагодити*, на мій погляд, перше значення («зробити, щоб працювало») надто домінує над другим («пристосовувати під себе, під якусь мету») — коли я чую «налагодити/полагодити щось», у мене асоціація «воно зламалося». Але більшість сучасного програмного забезпечення за умовчуванням має такі конфігурації, з якими воно просто працює (хай навіть і невідповідно до чиїхось потреб чи уподобань).

Я б особисто зупинився на більш-менш уживаному зараз **налаштувати**. Зокрема Microsoft у Microsoft Terminology Collection як відповідник до *configure* [наводить](//www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=configure&langID=Ukrainian&Source=true&productid=All%20Products) *налаштовувати* (у програмному забезпеченні від Microsoft уживається: *налаштування*, *налаштувати*, *настроїти*, *настройки*, *настроювання*). Так само KDE використовує *налаштувати* (наприклад: «configure KImageMapEditor» → «налаштувати KImageMapEditor», «configure KHTML Browser Part» → «налаштувати компонент перегляду KHTML» тощо).

Answer (score 3):

Англійсько-український словник з ІТ 1999–2011рр.

> [configure](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=configure&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)= налагоджувати {?}, **налаштовувати** {?}
>
> [application](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=application&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)  = (прикладна, застосовна) програма

Отже, можна замість "налагодити" використати "налаштувати":

You can configure application... — Ви можете **налаштувати** програму...

Answer (score 3):

Для перекладу слова "configure" як "налаштовувати" дуже критичним є контекст використання слова.

*Коротко*: для більшості випадків, це слово не підходить, адже конфігурування, зазвичай, можна проводити неодноразово/часто і воно, зазвичай,  не пов'язано з тим, щоб робити що-небудь придатним для роботи, користування(часто це буває лише один раз) і т.п., а пов'язано зі зміною параметрів чогось для того, щоб користування чимось відбувалося з більшим комфортом/задоволенням/зручністю.

Витяг із [onlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/):

> Перевірте вживання дієслова налаштовувати і в разі потреби замініть:
>   **настроювати** — налагоджувати, регулювати, робити придатним для роботи;
>  
>   припасовувати якусь систему (програмне забезпечення, прилад, пристрій тощо) до потреб користувача;
>   **встановлювати, задавати** — надавати певному параметру конкретного значення.
>   [(більше прикладів на оригінальній сторінці onlinecorrector)](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/)
>   *АЛЕ:*
>   **налаштовувати** — готувати що-небудь, виконувати початкову підготовку системи до роботи.
>   Для з’єднання з мережею **налаштуйте** маршрутизатор (користувач уперше готує систему до подальшого використання).

Крім того, тлумачення слова "налаштувати" від онлайнкоректора є абсолютно ідентичним до [тлумачення СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=55245&page=1759). Таким чином, `налаштовувати` не завжди є коректним перекладом, частіше навіть навпаки.

Я, особисто, повністю погоджуюся із онлайнкоректором щодо цього та [щодо більш правильного перекладу слова в більшості контекстах](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/), а саме:

> 1. Зміна параметрів чогось(зміна властивостей системи).
> 2. Змінити конфігурацію(змінити набір параметрів як сукупність).

Comment: Тобто на думку OnlineCorrector слово _лаштувати_ (_налаштовувати_) варто використовувати лише у випадках, коли дія одноразова? (Чи я неправильно зрозумів?) Можливо, але щось я сумніваюся. А хтось окрім OnlineCorrector цю думку поділяє? (P.S.: дякую за виправлення:).)

Comment: Наскільки я знаю, люди в онлайнкоректорі верифікують інформацію перед тим, як розміщувати її. Аналогів онлайнкоректора я  не знаю, де б пояснювалися відмінності у вживанні слів і т.д., проте в мене є СУМ-20 визначення - http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=55245&page=1759
Як бачите воно означає те, саме, що стверджує онлайнкоректор.

Comment: Тобто мається на увазі на configure в значенні первинної підготовки чогось, зазвичай, якогось пристрою до _першого_ використання. Чи це одноразова дія? Навряд. Чи це дія, котра повинна проводитися рідко(надзвичайно рідко)? Безсумнівно.
Я, зазвичай, перекладаю `configure something` як `змінювати параметри чогось`. Параметри можна змінювати скільки завгодно разів.
http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/

Comment: @Sasha Я відредагував відповідь, зараз вона має бути кращою.

Comment: Можливо, Ви маєте рацію, але я, якщо чесно, не бачу як із тлумачень СУМ-20 випливає, що це _первинна_ відготовка до _першого_ використання. («1. Готувати що-небудь або приводити до стану готовності».) Щодо OnlineCorrector, те саме — я не кажу, що вони неправі, можливо, вони навіть на 100% праві, але чим вони керуються, висуваючи такі твердження, мені поки не зрозуміло. (Але в будь-якому випадку дякую за відповідь. Навіть якщо висвітлений погляд, припустімо, неправильний — але такий погляд існує, і Ви навели джерело, тож…)

Comment: @Sasha Так, там цього не вказано, а втім, це _підготовка до використання_.
А `configure` - це, зазвичай, НЕ підготовка до використання(хоча іноді це так), а дія, пов'язана зі зміною якихось параметрів в чомусь(в приладі, грі і т/д).